# How can i merge more than 2 images with PHP?

Tags: php, gd, pixel

I'm trying to merge multiple images more than 3 with PHP

that's the code i'm using this code for merging two pictures only

```
$primary = imagecreatefrompng('redfeather.png'); //350 x 350
$secondary = imagecreatefrompng('bluebody.png'); //350 x 350
imagecopymerge($primary, $secondary, 0, 0, 0, 0, 350, 350, 50);
```

I couldn't find any codes for multiple picture merging. which functions i should use? Thanks

Comment: Just do the same thing again?

Comment: @Andreas hmm. a yhing like this? imagecopymerge($primary, $secondary, $tertiary, 0, 0, 0, 0, 350, 350, 50);

Comment: I was more thinking `imagecopymerge($primary, $thirdary, $tertiary, 0, 0, 0, 0, 350, 350, 50);` then $primary should be a mix of all three

Comment: @Andreas i tried your and said. must has 8 parameters  but that has 9

Comment: wait. did you mean creating this? imagecopymerge($primary, $secondary, 0, 0, 0, 0, 350, 350, 50); and imagecopymerge($primary, $tertiary, 0, 0, 0, 0, 350, 350, 50);

Comment: Yes. That is what I meant. You merge 1 & 2, then 1,2 & 3.